# What's the difference b/w the 2 ways to load a module dynamically?

Tags: perl

```
=any
            eval qq(
                use $$category_r[0];
                );
            die $? if $?;
=cut
            require "$$category_r[0].pm";
```

Now only `require` is working for me,I don't know why the 1st one doesn't work as expected...

Even this is not working:

```
my $pkg = "A";
eval {
    use $pkg;
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

Try [Module::Load](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Module-Load-0.18/lib/Module/Load.pm) if you want to load modules on the fly.

It works for both filenames and modules. It is safer than

```
my $module = "strict; warn 'PWNED'";
eval "use $module";
```

Also, as @daxim points out, it explains what's going on.

Comment: +1 yes please, this documents the intent of the programmer much more nicely.

Comment: but its documentation is wrong in claiming require EXPR needs a platform-specific filename: require works such that "Module/Name.pm" will be correct on any platform.

Answer (score 2):

You should be checking [`$@`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$@), not `$?`.  Is this the actual code that doesn't work?  Presumably you don't have it enclosed in pod for real.

For use, `$$category_r[0]` should be something like `Module::Name`, while your require is expecting `Module/Name`.

Comment: `my $pkg = "A";
eval {
    use $pkg;
    };`,why is this causing error?

Comment: you mean `eval qq( use $pkg );`  `eval {}`  just traps runtime errors and is compiled in the normal compile time step, so the use happens earlier than you want (and has to have a constant package name)